How do I evaluate the Cauchy principal value of $\int_{0}^{2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt {x}\ln(x)}$?
I want to evaluate the Cauchy principal value of,
$$\int_{0}^{2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt {x}\ln(x)}$$
As per the definition of Principal value,
$$\text{PV}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\lim_{q\to0^{+}}\int_{a}^{c-q}f(x)dx+\int_{c+q}^{b}f(x)dx$$
Where c is point of discontinuity in the given range. So the given integral would be,
$$\lim_{q\to 0^{+}}\int_{0}^{1-q}\frac{dx}{\sqrt x\ln(x)}+\int_{1+q}^{2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt x\ln(x)} $$
Substitution of $u=1-x$ and $t=x-1$ in the second leads them to have the same bounds and at last i have the following integral,
$$\lim_{q\to 0^{+}}\int_{q}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{1-x}\ln(1-x)+\sqrt{1+x}\ln(1+x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)}$$
Now I got no clue on how to proceed evaluating the integral.
Further, can the similar method be used to find the PV of the integrals of the form,
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{n}\ln(x)}dx$$  where $n\in [0,1)$?
As per the answer given by Átila Correia, I wonder if the following is true,
$$\int \frac{dx}{x^{n}\ln(x)}$$
$$(1-n)\int \frac{dx}{x^{n}\ln(x^{1-n})}$$
$$\int\frac{d(x^{1-n})}{\ln(x^{1-n})}$$
$$\int\frac{dy}{\ln(y)}$$
Please let me know if there are any mistakes or improvements to be made.

I do not know if it helps, but you can handle the indefinite integral as follows:
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x}\ln(x)} = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{2\sqrt{x}\ln(\sqrt{x})} = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}(\sqrt{x})}{\ln(\sqrt{x})} = \int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\ln(u)}
\end{align*}

Your suggestion follows the idea of the logarithmic integral function, which helps bypass the singularity at $u = 1$.

@MrMathster Interesting! Thanks for sharing.

@Átila Correia, thanks for the answer. Could you please see my edited question. Using your idea, i provided a generalization. Please let know if there are any mistakes

@RAHUL You are welcome! I am glad I could help. As far as I can tell, there are no mistakes (just an extra $\mathrm{d}x$).
